# Php code to know from which site does my site's url is redirected?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, curl, http-referer

My client have two sites(suppose a.com and b.com) already on live and we don't have access to change there and the there is a link from where it will redirect to the new site(suppose c.com) developed my me but I have to find and save the record that from which site(a.com or b.com) it was redirected to the new c.com site.
Till now I found the answer is

```
$_referer = $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"];
```

If you have best solution for it please answer me.
Thank You!

Comment: That's exactly what the referrer is for. To tell you where the user came from. What problems are you having with it? What do you need that referrer isn't giving you?

Comment: @Christian Varga  http referer is not a good solution so I am searching for the alternative solution

Comment: _"not a good solution"_ is not a problem; it's a symptom or an opinion. You need to explain **why** and **what** the problem is. If you don't define the problem, we can't provide a solution. Otherwise, you may as well just Google "Alternative to http referrer". There's nothing we can provide that a Google search won't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the most reliable option is to add the source site to the links, as its your site.

so on a.com a link from a may be

```
www.c.com?from=a
```

on c, the value would be  in `$_GET['from']`

HTTP_REFERER is unreliable as it is browser set

Comment: I dont have access to the site a.com and b.com to change the link coz c is also a old site but I am updating the system I need a solution that I can track from c.com that where it is redirected from.

Comment: http is stateless, so you have no other option then than the the unreliable HTTP_REFERER